# Interaction Service vs Interaction Request Objects

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, prism

I'd like to know when using Prism, Interaction Request Objects is preferable to using Interaction Service pattern.
As for me, Interaction Service should be used in simple cases, i.e. when you have a standard message popup, and only the text content is going to be changed. On the other hand, Interaction Request Objects is more suitable when the UI is more complicated. But Interaction Service is much easier to implement and requires less code.
What do you think?

Comment: I have the same question.  Anyone...

Answer (score 2):

The huge drawback of using an interaction service to display a message box is the parent window - or rather the lack of one.

What window should you provide as the parent of the message box, from the view model or service implementation? If you choose Application.Mainwindow, you're making a huge assumption about the overall application layout.

The only entity in the process that knows *how* to display the interaction is the view. Whether that be using a message box, or in-page overlay.

There are few valid arguments in favour if using an interaction service. The one often used is that it's easier. This may be true, but is also true of many other things that shouldn't be done, e.g. code behind, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that an Interaction Service can be suitable for common interaction behaviour such as MessageBoxes etc.

In my opinion, it boils down to class responsibility. In other words, do you want the ViewModel or the View to be responsible for specifying what type of interaction should take place?

Consider a basic Interaction Service interface:

```
public interface IInteractionService{
    MessageBoxResult ShowMessageBox(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button);
}
```

It's fairly obvious from observing the interface what type of behaviour ShowMessageBox is going to produce. This gives the ViewModel some degree of control in terms of specifying what type of interaction behaviour it expects to occur. The problem with this approach is your ViewModel now has a dependency on IInteractionService as well as being explicit in it's interaction behaviour expectations. This could make your ViewModel less reusable.

With Interaction Objects, you can place more of the responsibility of interaction behaviour on the View. In other words, you can change the behaviour and appearance of the interaction without directly affecting the ViewModel. For example, V1 of the interaction request could display a simple MessageBox. V2 of the interaction request could be a more complex dialog requiring more user interaction that a simple button click. This kind of interaction behaviour change can be managed without requiring modification of the ViewModel.  This can be useful if you have a UI designer working on the project who wants the option to swap out or change the behaviour or appearance of a view tied to an interaction request.

You could use both strategies if you wanted. In other words, an Interaction Service for common interaction behaviours and Interaction Objects for more complex behaviour.

To summarize, Interaction Services can be easier to use but Interaction Objects can make your ViewModels more reusable, in my opinion.